# Error-handling middleware doesn't always work

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I'm building a example website using Express and I hit something I don't quite understand. 
Error-handling middleware(s) should be last one(s) in the pipeline, if I understand correctly. For example, works just fine:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', './views');

app.use(express.static('./public'));
http.createServer(app).listen(portNumber, function() { });

app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome!');
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(500).send('something broke!');
});

app.get('/error', function(req, res, next) {
    somethingNonExistent(2016);
});
```

However, if I register that middleware before http.createServer call, but after all other middlewares were registered, it won't work - my code isn't called:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static('./public'));

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(500).send('something broke!');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(portNumber, function() { });

app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome!');
});

app.get('/error', function(req, res, next) {
    somethingNonExistent(2016);
});
```

What did I miss here? My guess is that app.get calls use some middleware internally and it gets messed up. 
I use Express 3.2.6 and Node.js 0.10.29, if that makes any difference

Comment: please comment on the downvotes

Comment: I'm not sure about the downvotes, but what stopped me from taking any time to answer is the irrelevant extra code. The best way to get an answer is to post the most simplistic use case you can come up with, not post your entire app. Nobody really enjoys debugging, let alone debugging someone else's code. You don't need console logging the port, setting environment configs, math to calculate the length of a day, etc. `var app = express();app.use(something); app.get("/hello",...); /*your attempt at error handling*/`

Comment: @cdbajorin point taken. I'll update the post

Comment: @chester89 createServer was deprecated some time ago. See the Express documentation for a basic example (http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)

Comment: @chester89 Worth noting that in Express 4 the error doesn't get handled in both cases

Comment: Routes then Errors handlers - First `app.use('/', indexRouter);` , then `app.use(errorHandler)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define routes/middleware, the `path` you specify is used to see if it matches with incoming requests. Your request will always be routed to the first match. A request might have multiple matches, so order matters here. You can hit the next matching route/middleware by calling the `next()` function.

When you mount middleware using [`app.use`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use) without specifying a path, every path is eligible to hit that middleware. So, if it's the first thing you mount, every request will use that middleware.

If you want a catch all error handler, you'll want the opposite - you should mount middleware at the very end of your route definitions. You'll need to call the `next` function in your handler to actually reach this middleware:

```
app.get('/hello', function(req, res, next) {
  ...
  // Let's pretend that there was some error
  next()
});

// After all of your route definitions...
app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.status(500).send('something broke!');
})
```

Note that if no route exists for the current path, you will also hit this catch all middleware.

Comment: also, I suspect your answer applies for both versions 3 and 4? just curious

Answer (score 1):

*Docs*

http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

> You define error-handling middleware last, after other app.use() and
>   routes calls; for example:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // logic
});
```

---

*The Internal*

For ease of understanding, you can imagine the pipeline. When your controller receives a request, inside Express, it looks like this

```
try {
  fn(req, res, next); // your controller
} catch (err) {
  next(err);
}
```

So, then your code throw error, it will call `next` with `err`. Basically, it's the same as call `next(new Error())`. After that, express trying to find next middleware with 4 arguments in middleware pipeline. In your situation error handler declared **before** your shady controller, so he doesn't involved.

Technically, there is no difference between the controller and middlewares. Optionally you can pass in the controller `next` parameter , and call it to pass through the pipeline further. If you don't call `next()`, you finish processing the request.